# Title edit that adds a wrong limitation - why allow it to stay?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

[This edit](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14182) completely changed the focus of the question title by adding an irrelevant term.

The question asks what should happen if, during a **kick-off**, the ball strikes the goal. It adds a brief side note on what should happen if that occurred during a field goal attempt.

The change to the title conflicts with the original intent: it suggests the question is about one thing when it is clearly not restricted nor focused in such a way.

Why should this edit be kept and not rolled back?

On a general note, when reviewing, **please read the entire existing post *and then* compare the edits**. It is not enough for changes to look okay at a glance. They must make sense in the context of that particular post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being a little bit unfair here. The question itself does say

> What about a field goal attempt?

While the main thrust of the question is about kickoffs, field goals are mentioned as well. Now then, that's not a good Stack Exchange question as it's actually two questions, but there most definitely is a mention of field goals in there.

I'll remove all mention of field goals from the question, as the existing answers refer just to kickoffs.

Comment: Asking related secondary questions is common practise and there are a lot of well-deserved questions of that kind. Given the main thrust is about kickoffs and field goals aren't mentioned until the last line, this edit was not reasonable, hence I pointed it out.